# GAE Not able to access Public methods of Entity Class in Clientside

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, objectify

I am using Objectify in to do data store operations in endpoint classes.
I have an Entity class

there is a public method :

```
    public void setRegistrationRecord(RegistrationRecord registrationRecord) {
        this.registrationRecord = Ref.create(Key.create(RegistrationRecord.class, registrationRecord.getId()));
    }
```

In client side I am not able to access this Method

please let me know What wrong I am doing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what about class is it `public`.? not able to means.. any errors?

Comment: @satya  yes it is a public class.

Answer (score 1):

Objectify is a server-side framework. Creating a Key requires the GAE SDK, which is not available client-side.

Comment: thanks for your response. 

Endpoint methods not allow more than one Entity class in parameter. So store an entity in data store I need to first Create entity and then key.  It is only possible in Server side.

Is there any way to do in client side ?